# What data type can I use for separate month (January, February, etc) and year (2012, 2020, etc) columns?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqldatatypes

I am currently trying to copy a csv file into a created table in PostgreSQL. The file contains a month and a year column in the following formats --> Month: January, February, March, April, etc. Year: 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, etc.

Please what data type do I use for these columns in the created table. I tried using DATE, but it did not work. This is what I tried earlier;

```
CREATE TABLE IBREW (
sales_id int,
months date,
years date,
)
```

Comment: It is pretty staring forward to convert the pair (January, 2020) to a date 2020-01-01

Answer (score 1):

Do not store as Month Name and Year store it as an actual date, you can always get what ever format you want from a date. If you store as separate columns you will end up jumping through all kinds of hoops to get what a DATE type gives you simply. The problem then becomes: *How to generate as actual given the month name and year.* Postgres provides 2 functions to the rescue [MAKE_DATE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-datetime.html) and an array function [ARRAY_POSITION](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-array.html).  
First step Create an array containing month names in calendar order then use array_position to convert to month number. Second step use the result in the make_date procedure to get an actual DATE.  
Now this can make a nasty looking query so I would the whole thing behind a SQL function. Not actually necessary since it consists on a single SQL statement.

```
create or replace 
function make_real_date( month_name_in text   
                       , year_in       integer
                       ) 
   returns date 
  language sql 
as $$
with mlist (month_name) as 
     ( select array [ 'january'
                    , 'february'
                    , 'march'
                    , 'aprial'
                    , 'may'
                    , 'june'
                    , 'july'
                    , 'august'
                    , 'september'
                    , 'october'
                    , 'november' 
                    , 'december' 
                    ]
      ) --select * from mlist;  
select make_date ( year  => year_in
                 , month => (select array_position(month_name, lower(month_name_in)) from mlist)  
                 , day   => 1
                 ) ;
$$;
```

See [example here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=e9911bd81059ff7ecc0c9b2a145b329d), Note: When an invalid month name the function returns null.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to store a month and a year, use two integers (or even `smallint`). I would not store the month *names* because dealing with numbers will make your life a lot easier - think about sorting or applying range conditions. You can always translate a number to a name when you *display* the data in your application.

```
create table ibrew 
(
  sales_id int, 
  month int check (month between 1 and 12), 
  year int check (year > 0)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't convert the month data, you'd need to use an an [enumerable](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-enum.html) or [character type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html) for month. Year would be an integer.

**Enum:**

```sql
CREATE TYPE month AS ENUM ('January', 'February', 'March', ...);
create table ibrew 
(
  sales_id int, 
  month month, 
  year int
)
```

**Text Month:**

```sql
create table ibrew 
(
  sales_id int, 
  month text, 
  year int
)
```

You can also use a varchar or at a constraint to limit the size of month if that's helpful to your application.

Read more about [postgres data types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype.html).